# r Shiny Decision Tree Data Input

Tags: r, tree, shiny, decision-tree

I'm making a shiny application that determines a decision tree model and then comes up with predictions based on user inputs.

The model is developed like so:

```
tr<-prune.tree(tree(Y ~ ., dataset,split="gini"),best=4)
```

There are a total of 20 variables, and only 5 are actually used in the tree. So, I would like to create my app such that the user only needs to input these 5 variables, rather than all of them. Here's what I tried (only showing the important code):

In server.r:

```
 output$treepred<-renderText({
predict(tr,data.frame(PREVIOUS=input$numeric6,NR_EMPLOYED=input$numeric1,CAMPAIGN=input$numeric7,EMP_VAR_RATE=input$numeric8,CONS_PRICE_IDX=input$numeric9),type="class")
})
```

In ui.r:

```
box(textOutput("treepred"))
```

Simply running this returns me an error "object 'AGE' not found" (where AGE is an *unused* variable). If I reconstruct the tree using only the variables that were found to be relevant, I get a totally different (and far worse) tree. (I've also tried including those irrelevant variables but setting them to NULL or NA, but that didn't work either.)

In essence, the issue is that r wishes for the user to input all of the data, when they really needn't. Does anyone know how to get around this?

EDIT:

A small example:

```
    dir <- "Your directory"
    dataset <- read.csv(paste(dir, "Data.csv",sep = ""))
    dataset[, c(1, 11:13)] <- lapply(dataset[, c(1, 11:13)],as.integer)
    dataset[, c(2:10, 14, 20)] <- lapply(dataset[, c(2:10,14,20)], as.factor)
    dataset[, c(15:19)] <- lapply(dataset[, c(15:19)],as.numeric)
    dataset$PDAYS[dataset$PDAYS == 999] <- NA #this is NA by the definition of the data

    library(tree)

    tree<-prune.tree(tree(Y ~ ., dataset,split="gini"),best=4)

    plot(tree, type="uniform")
    text(tree, pretty=0)

    predict(tree,newdata=dataset,type="class")
    #The above all works perfectly.

    summary(tree)
    #This tells us which variables are relevant

    predict(tree,newdata=data.frame(PREVIOUS=1,CAMPAIGN=1,EMP_VAR_RATE=50,CONS_PRICE_IDX=100,NR_EMPLOYED=5000))
    #returns error: object 'AGE' not found.

    #Retraining the tree with only relevant variables:
    tree2<-prune.tree(tree(Y ~ PREVIOUS+NR_EMPLOYED+CAMPAIGN+EMP_VAR_RATE+CONS_PRICE_IDX, dataset,split="gini"),best=4)

    plot(tree2, type="uniform")
    text(tree2, pretty=0)

    #This tree is completely different and only ever predicts "no"
```

Here is the data:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/d11tc9d23mw64s5/Data.csv?dl=0

Comment: I can't try it now, but try to replace `textOutput`by `verbatimTextOutuput`, and replace `renderText`by `renderPrint`.

Comment: @Smich7 Thank you, but unfortunately, this results in the same error.

Comment: Damn sorry, is there a variable "AGE" in `dataset` ? Because if it is true, you don't give any "AGE" variable in the testing dataframe in the `predict` function. Dataframes in `tree` and `predict` should have the same number of variables which have the same names. Then you should not use `Y ~ .` but `Y ~ PREVIOUS+NR_EMPLOYED+CAMPAIGN+EMP_VAR_RATE+CONS_PRICE_IDX` when you train your tree.

Comment: @Smich7 There is indeed an AGE variable in the dataset, but the tree model doesn't actually use that variable (you can see this if you type summary(tr)). I also did try training the tree with the method you suggested, but unfortunately that produces a completely different (and basically unusable) tree.

Comment: Okay, I can't really know where the problem that produces a such tree comes from. But while you train on all variables and do not gives a dataset with all the variable in your `predict` you'll get the error `"object 'AGE' not found"`. What do you mean by unsuable ?

Comment: I think you should make a toy example with that data set and just the code you mentioned here, and see if you still get that problem. Without Shiny because this probably has nothing to do with Shiny. If you still can't figure it out then trim the data set down and see if it is still there. When it is small enough you can post it.

Comment: @Smich7 I totally understand what you're saying and I agree with you, but I've been told by several (unhelpful haha) professors that this should be possible. And when I say 'unusable' I mean it only ever predicts the same thing ("no")

Comment: @MikeWise I'm not exactly sure what you mean by 'trim the dataset down', but I will post a proper example in a moment (Sorry, did you request for me to post the example or the dataset?).

Comment: Please post both.

Comment: @MikeWise Done. I hope a dropbox link is sufficient.

Comment: Out to dinner for tonight now but if it is still open will look tomorrow

Comment: @MikeWise That's perfect, thank you so much. It's 3:00am here so I'll check this out again in the morning myself.

Comment: @MikeWise I've noticed that I don't have this issue when using different packages.. but the tree package provides me a result over twice as accurate as the other packages. Could it be the algorithm of the tree package? Is it programmed in such a way that utilises all variables even if they are not shown? If that's the case maybe it would be better for me to write my own code to create a tree replicating the one created by the tree package.

Comment: Been looking at it, it is interesting. Will have an answer soon. I think it is just "complicated", and your data has a high degree of "randomness", i.e. the variables you have don't predict the outcome that reliably. Which leads to "unstable trees".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I had a look. The thing that was puzzling of course is why the second tree looks so much different than the first tree. The root split should be the same if you are keeping the same variables, since the dimension with the maximum information gain should not change. I went over it for awhile, but you can actually see the problem in the tree outputs. Here is the first tree:

```
> tree
node), split, n, deviance, yval, (yprob)
      * denotes terminal node

 1) root 1515 1983.00 yes ( 0.3617 0.6383 )  
   2) PREVIOUS < 1.5 865 1167.00 yes ( 0.4035 0.5965 )  
     4) CAMPAIGN < 1.5 460  618.40 yes ( 0.3978 0.6022 )  
       8) EMP_VAR_RATE < -3.2 91  110.70 yes ( 0.2967 0.7033 ) *
       9) EMP_VAR_RATE > -3.2 369  502.70 yes ( 0.4228 0.5772 )  
        18) CONS_PRICE_IDX < 93.2845 221  303.50 no ( 0.5566 0.4434 ) *
        19) CONS_PRICE_IDX > 93.2845 148  157.10 yes ( 0.2230 0.7770 ) *
     5) CAMPAIGN > 1.5 405  548.20 yes ( 0.4099 0.5901 )  
      10) CAMPAIGN < 2.5 256  338.70 yes ( 0.3750 0.6250 )  
        20) NR_EMPLOYED < 5087.65 193  220.80 yes ( 0.2591 0.7409 ) *
        21) NR_EMPLOYED > 5087.65 63   73.47 no ( 0.7302 0.2698 ) *
      11) CAMPAIGN > 2.5 149  206.00 yes ( 0.4698 0.5302 ) *
   3) PREVIOUS > 1.5 650  800.80 yes ( 0.3062 0.6938 ) *
```

And here is the second.

```
> tree2
node), split, n, deviance, yval, (yprob)
      * denotes terminal node

 1) root 41188 29000 no ( 0.88735 0.11265 )  
   2) PREVIOUS < 0.5 35563 21240 no ( 0.91168 0.08832 )  
     4) NR_EMPLOYED < 5087.65 2634  3496 no ( 0.62073 0.37927 ) *
     5) NR_EMPLOYED > 5087.65 32929 15850 no ( 0.93495 0.06505 ) *
   3) PREVIOUS > 0.5 5625  6522 no ( 0.73351 0.26649 )  
     6) PREVIOUS < 1.5 4561  4713 no ( 0.78799 0.21201 )  
      12) NR_EMPLOYED < 5087.65 1433  1986 no ( 0.51082 0.48918 ) *
      13) NR_EMPLOYED > 5087.65 3128  1820 no ( 0.91496 0.08504 ) *
     7) PREVIOUS > 1.5 1064  1475 no ( 0.50000 0.50000 ) *
>
```

The first tree found the maximum gini split at `PREVIOUS = 1.5`, the second one at 0.5. However you can also see that the first tree was only looking at 1515 points for some reason, but the second one was looking at 41188, many more.

Why? If you look at the formulas you see that the first tree looked at all the columns and the second one at a subset. So lets count all the rows without missing data:

```
> sum(complete.cases(dataset))
[1] 1515
```

And that is your answer. The rows with missing data are not being looked at for the first tree, but they are in the second tree as you restricted it to certain columns. No wonder the trees are different....

As to your other problem, that is just the way the `predict.tree` algorithm works, it makes sure all the data was there before preceding. This allows it to use coding infrastructure in common with the other `predict.xxx` functions. The answer is easy, just make sure you have dummy data in all the columns you do not care about. You can use something like this for example:

```
ddf1 <- dataset[1,]
ddf1$PREVIOUS <- 1
ddf1$CAMPAIGN <- 1
ddf1$EMP_VAR_RATE <- 50
ddf1$CONS_PRICE_IDX <- 100
ddf1$CONS_PRICE_IDX <- 5000
predict(tree,newdata=ddf1)
```

A final point is that even in your second tree it wasn't simply predicting "no" all the time. The probabilities of those no's (as can also be seen in the tree output) varied quite a bit. And you can access these branches and values programmatically by looking at the `tree$frame` data frame.

Comment: I see.. It's all due to the NA values (all of which are due to one variable, which I will now remove). So theoretically, I should get the same tree if I try this again without the problematic variable. Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, I made a final note too just now.

Comment: I had no idea the tree package took those probabilities into account also, I thought it was just party and rpart that did that. Thank you so much haha I was actually trying to figure out how to access those probabilities if they did exist.